# Nuget - Don't see allow nuget to download missing packages during build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, nuget

I get  a message saying the following:

> Error    1   Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open
>   the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on Package Manager node and
>   check 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.' You can
>   also give consent by setting the environment variable
>   'EnableNuGetPackageRestore' to 'true'.

When I go to Tools -> Options, I do not see Package Manager and underneath I see Package Sources and Recent Packages. I do not see anywhere where I can set Allow Nuget to download missing packages during build though.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The option to give consent in the UI has been added with NuGet Package Manager 1.8. It's the 3rd item under Tools-> Options-> Package Manager-> General : "Package Restore : Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build".

Please make sure NuGet is up-to-date in Tools->Extension Manager.

Alternatively you can give consent by setting the `EnableNuGetPackageRestore` Environment variable to `true`.

Comment: Updating nuget fixed the problem

Comment: I had to use the environment variable after doing everything else and it still didn't work. (admittingly i had it disabled, had packages folder checked into svn and then deleted it, so maybe I had other corrupt state)

Answer (score 60):

I found I needed an extra couple of steps to get it to download the packages

1. Check Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build

   [image]
2. Check Always show solution in Projects and Solutions

   [image]
3. Right click on solution and Enable NuGet Package Restore

   [image]
4. Open Manage NuGet Packages and click Restore

   [image]

Comment: I don't have that context menu item for "Enable NuGet Package Restore" showing up in the Solution context menu - I have the latest version of NuGet (2.0.30717.9005) installed in VS 2012.  Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: +1 I didn't have that first menu itme either. Nevertheless clicking Restore solved the issue.

Comment: It is good advice to visit Manage NuGet Packages and click `restore`!

Comment: Like Guy Starbuck - I too do not have the option shown above.  Also, no button 'Restore' in yellow bar appears in the Manage NuGet Packages section - yet I still get the error described by OP.  Why does MS keep changing stuff so versions of the same tool exhibit different behaviors and differing verbiage - harder than hell to search for a solution...

Answer (score 2):

I did not seem to have the "Package Manager" node under Tools->Options [this was in Visual Studio 2013 :-)]. To get that node in there, I browsed to Tools -> Extensions and Updates and searched for nuget. Installing "NuGet for Visual Studio 2013" got me the node and the option to allow package restore!

Answer (score 1):

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and NuGet 2.0.

Someone had checked in a solution that used NuGet for various packages.  When I checked out the solution and built it, I got the same errors.  What's more, when I viewed the NuGet Package Manager from the Tools -> Options window, the Package Restore already had the appropriate check boxes checked.

I tried clicking the Clear Package Cache button.  After doing that, everything built correctly.

[image]

Comment: this worked for me on VS2012, both checkboxes were already checked, but clearing the package cache immediately resolved the error and allowed me to build. thanks!