# Hudson MSBuild and NLog

Tags: msbuild, dependencies, hudson

I have solution in SVN. Solution has reference to NLog installed to project via Nuget.
On test environment I installed hudson to get latest from SVN and build it.
When hudson try to build - build fails: 
 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "NLog". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

What is the correct way to setup NLog to be visible from test environment? 
Thank you.

Comment: It appears not hudson issue, just msbuild. You should set up EnableNuGetPackageRestore Environment variable to true.

Answer (score 0):

It appears not hudson issue, just msbuild. You should set up EnableNuGetPackageRestore Environment variable to true. As at here [Nuget - Don't see allow nuget to download missing packages during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261310/nuget-dont-see-allow-nuget-to-download-missing-packages-during-build)